# How to create a array of Strings in php?

Tags: php

i want to create a array of Strings like -

```
 String arr[2]={"tushar", "sah");
```

How will i do it?

Comment: Please see the manual, http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php, there are many examples there.

Comment: @chris85 u mean this  $array = array("foo", "bar", "hello", "world");?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Give it a try and see how to works.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$arr = ["tushar", "sah"];
```

Comment: This answer is php version specific, you should really be declaring $arr like this: $arr = array("tushar", "sah");